# How do I fix a drag and drop error in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to make a simple app using Typescript and React that allows users to add "projects". The form has 3 fields. On submit, the form adds the new user project to a list of "Active Projects". The user should then be able to drag-and-drop Active Projects into a Completed Projects list. I'm using the react-beautiful-dnd library for the drag-and-drop and uuid for the unique keys.

Here is my app layout:

components/ProjectInputForm.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

type ProjectInputFormProps = {
  onAdd: (title: string, description: string, people: number) => void;
};

const ProjectInputForm: React.FC<ProjectInputFormProps> = ({ onAdd }) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
  const [people, setPeople] = useState(0);

  const submitHandler = (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    onAdd(title, description, people);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={title}
        onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Title"
      />
      <textarea
        value={description}
        onChange={e => setDescription(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Description"
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        value={people}
        onChange={e => setPeople(parseInt(e.target.value))}
        placeholder="People"
      />
      <button type="submit">Add Project</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default ProjectInputForm;
```

components/ProjectList.tsx

```
import { Droppable, Draggable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';

type ProjectType = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  people: number;
};

type ProjectListProps = {
  projects: ProjectType[];
  listType: 'active' | 'completed';
  onDelete: (id: string) => void;
};

const ProjectList: React.FC<ProjectListProps> = ({
  projects,
  listType,
  onDelete,
}) => {
  return (
    <Droppable droppableId={listType}>
      {provided => (
        <div {...provided.droppableProps} ref={provided.innerRef}>
          <h2>
            {listType.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + listType.slice(1)} Projects
          </h2>
          {projects.map((project, index) => (
            <Draggable key={project.id} draggableId={project.id} index={index}>
              {provided => (
                <div
                  {...provided.draggableProps}
                  {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                  ref={provided.innerRef}
                >
                  <h3>{project.title}</h3>
                  <p>{project.description}</p>
                  <p>{project.people}</p>
                  <button onClick={() => onDelete(project.id)}>Delete</button>
                </div>
              )}
            </Draggable>
          ))}
          {provided.placeholder}
        </div>
      )}
    </Droppable>
  );
};

export default ProjectList;
```

App.tsx

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { DragDropContext } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import ProjectInputForm from './components/ProjectInputForm';
import ProjectList from './components/ProjectList';

type ProjectType = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  people: number;
};

function App() {
  const [activeProjects, setActiveProjects] = useState<ProjectType[]>([]);
  const [completedProjects, setCompletedProjects] = useState<ProjectType[]>([]);

  const addProject = (title: string, description: string, people: number) => {
    const newProject: ProjectType = {
      id: uuidv4(),
      title,
      description,
      people,
    };
    setActiveProjects([...activeProjects, newProject]);
  };

  const deleteProject = (list: 'active' | 'completed', id: string) => {
    if (list === 'active') {
      setActiveProjects(activeProjects.filter(project => project.id !== id));
    } else {
      setCompletedProjects(
        completedProjects.filter(project => project.id !== id)
      );
    }
  };

  const handleDragEnd = (result: any) => {
    if (!result.destination) return;

    const { source, destination } = result;

    if (source.droppableId !== destination.droppableId) {
      setActiveProjects(prevActiveProjects => {
        const sourceList =
          source.droppableId === 'active'
            ? prevActiveProjects
            : completedProjects;
        const destinationList =
          destination.droppableId === 'active'
            ? prevActiveProjects
            : completedProjects;

        const [removed] = sourceList.splice(source.index, 1);
        destinationList.splice(destination.index, 0, removed);

        if (source.droppableId === 'active') {
          setCompletedProjects([...destinationList]);
        } else {
          setCompletedProjects([...sourceList]);
        }

        return [...sourceList];
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}>
      <ProjectInputForm onAdd={addProject} />

      <ProjectList
        projects={activeProjects}
        listType="active"
        onDelete={id => deleteProject('active', id)}
      />

      <ProjectList
        projects={completedProjects}
        listType="completed"
        onDelete={id => deleteProject('completed', id)}
      />
    </DragDropContext>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Basically, the form adds projects fine, however, whenever the user tries to drag a project from the Active to Completed lists, it throws an error:

Invariant failed: Cannot find droppable entry with id [active]

To be specific, the error is thrown as soon as the user clicks and holds the project (so even before a drag or drop).

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated!!